# Using inline variable in calculate field code block

Tags: modelbuilder, arcgis-pro

I've got a model that just copies features from one feature class and appends them to another. If a user supplies a string variable in the `NewName` field, it overwrites the values for the `Name` field in the feature class. However, I can't get this working in the code block.

```
def calcName(Name, NewName):
    if len(NewName) == 0: #Meaning the user did not enter a variable here
        return Name
    else:
        return NewName

calcName(!Name!, '%NewName%')
```

This results in the field always being changed to `'%NewName%'` within the field. It doesn't matter what the string is, it always returns `'%NewName%'`. I can type `potato` in the `NewName` parameter and it will return `'%NewName%'`.

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can replicate what you're seeing. I'm not sure I can explain it, I'd expect that if no value was passed in to your `NewName` parameter, you'd be able to check for Len of 0 or None or something similar to that. I changed your logic to specifically test for `'%NewName%'` and it seems to do what you want to do. I know it looks weird, but it works. Give that a try?

```
def calcName(Name, NewName):
    if NewName == '%NewName%': #Meaning the user did not enter a variable here
        return Name
    else:
        return NewName

calcName(!Name!, '%NewName%')
```

Comment: It certainly does look a little strange but it works! Still can't comprehend why what I had doesn't work properly.

Comment: Its probably something to do with an optional parameter and being inline variable from MB to Python. It doesnt pass `none`, but passes the variable name itself when `none`. (just a guess)

Comment: This answer explains how to do it the neatly, if you would like to. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10567644/if-else-based-on-existence-of-python-function-optional-arguments

Comment: @KHibma looks like this doesn't actually work if you put a value in for NewName. If you leave it blank it's fine but if you type anything in the parameter it still only returns `!Name!`. Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm not in a position to test this right now. When I did though, it was producing the expected result for me with a name and when blank.